# If singular Quarks cannot exist on their own, then how is Quark-Gluon Plasma possible?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, states-of-matter, quark-gluon-plasma

To my understanding, QGP is a theoretical form of matter where quarks are freely floating around. I understand immense temperature and pressure is required to form this. Also to my knowledge, quarks cannot exist on their own, and must be binded to others in the form of protons/neutrons/pions. These two facts seem to contradict each other, and I am curious how QGP can exist when singular quarks cannot exist on their own.

Comment: You might sharpen your question by [reading up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark–gluon_plasma#How_the_quark–gluon_plasma_fits_into_the_general_scheme_of_physics). At high energy densities, quarks can float around virtually freely, in a soup of weakly-coupled quarks and gluons, quark matter. You appreciate asymptotic freedom, the weakening of gluons forces at high energies/temperatures, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt to remove a quark from a gluon stores enough potential energy in the colour field to form a meson, which happens instead of the quark's removal. This effect results in confinement. However, the hadron has a nonzero size, in part because of asymptotic freedom (the colour force is very weak at short length scales). In extremely dense matter, the volume to which a hadron would theoretically confine its quarks is larger than the volume per hadron. Assigning a volume to each hadron, they now overlap, allowing quarks to move between such volumes despite the otherwise expected confinement. This results in the quark-gluon plasma, which has already been [empirically](https://home.cern/science/physics/heavy-ions-and-quark-gluon-plasma) [achieved](https://home.cern/tags/quark-gluon-plasma).